# How to reset data or set default data on a RecyclerView item when it is added to the recyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a textView that holds a number value that when the add button is clicked it adds one to it and when the subtract button is clicked it subtracts 1 from it. But when i add a new item to the recyclerView the number value will be automatically set to the last items value. So if the first item numberValue is 3 the second items number value will be 3 when it is added. I want the textView to automatically be 0 when a new item is added to the recyclerView

```
public class PlatesAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PlatesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

//Declaring a List<> of Plates
private List<Plates> mPlatesList;

//Variable to hold total numberOfPlates being used
int amountOfPlates = 0;
String amountOfPlatesString;

//OnBindViewHolder
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PlatesAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final TextView amountOfPlatesTextView = holder.amountOfPlatesTextView;

    //BUTTONS add 1 or subtract 1 from amountOfPlates;
    Button addAmountOfPlatesButton = holder.addButton;
    Button subtractAmountOfPlatesButton = holder.subButton;

    addAmountOfPlatesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addPlates();
            amountOfPlatesString = Integer.toString(amountOfPlates);
            amountOfPlatesTextView.setText(amountOfPlatesString);
        }
    });

    subtractAmountOfPlatesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            subtractPlates();
            amountOfPlatesString = Integer.toString(amountOfPlates);
            amountOfPlatesTextView.setText(amountOfPlatesString);
        }
    });
}

public void addPlatesLayout(Plates plate) {
    if (mPlatesList == null) mPlatesList = new ArrayList();
    //plate.setPlateWeight(a);
    mPlatesList.add(plate);
    //notifyDataSetChanged();
    notifyItemInserted(mPlatesList.size() - 1);
}

public int addPlates() {
    amountOfPlates++;
    return amountOfPlates;
}

public int subtractPlates() {
    amountOfPlates--;
    return amountOfPlates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to setText in OnBindViewHolder.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PlatesAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final TextView amountOfPlatesTextView = holder.amountOfPlatesTextView;
    amountOfPlatesTextView.setText("0");
    //BUTTONS add 1 or subtract 1 from amountOfPlates;
    Button addAmountOfPlatesButton = holder.addButton;
    Button subtractAmountOfPlatesButton = holder.subButton;

    addAmountOfPlatesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addPlates();
            amountOfPlatesString = Integer.toString(amountOfPlates);
            amountOfPlatesTextView.setText(amountOfPlatesString);
        }
    });

    subtractAmountOfPlatesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            subtractPlates();
            amountOfPlatesString = Integer.toString(amountOfPlates);
            amountOfPlatesTextView.setText(amountOfPlatesString);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: didnt work the numbervalue will still be set to the previous items number value.